# Abstract class properties without get and set methods in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, abstract-class

I want to implement an abstract class.
I want to have abstract properties but I do not want to implement *get* and *set* methods in the subclasses.

Consider the following:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Human(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def say_hi(self):
        pass
        print(f'hi {self.name}')

class NamedMan(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Omer'
        super().__init__()

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'hi {self.name}')

man = NamedMan()
man.say_hi()
```

In the subclass, this is how I want to set the property `name`, but it doesn't work because I need to explicitly use the `@property` decorator.

I'm looking for a solution to allow me to use `self.name`, but still require it as an abstract property.